# Calling tk.Destroy() prevents me from being able to use additional tk windows later on?

Tags: tkinter

I wanted to close all existing tk windows before continuing to run my code, and I don't have handles to the `Tk()` objects already. So I thought I would try the following minimal example of my error, which uses `Tk.destroy()`:

```py
import tkinter as tk
Tk = tk.Tk()
Tk.destroy()

window1 = tk.Tk()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

f1,ax1 = plt.subplots()

frame1 = tk.Frame(window1,width=300,height=300,bg='blue')
frame1.place(x=0,y=0)

canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f1,frame1)

canvas1.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0,column=0)

canvas1.draw()
```

EDIT:

Output:

```
can't invoke "event" command: application has been destroyed

while executing

"event generate $w <<ThemeChanged>>"

(procedure "ttk::ThemeChanged" line 6)

invoked from within

"ttk::ThemeChanged"
```

Comment: The code works for me. Python 3.9.5, Win 10, Tcl 8.6. Can you please post the full error traceback?

Comment: Just updated the comment with the full traceback. I'm python 3.7.6, Win 10, Tcl 8.6.8. It's possible it's just a python version issue, but seems odd.

Comment: Can you please add `print(tk._default_root == window1)` after the `window1 = tk.Tk()`. Does it print out `True` or `False` (it should be `True`).

Comment: Does matplotlib use theming? It seems odd you would get a theming error since you don't import ttk. Just to be clear, you're claiming the first block of code in your question will give you the exact error in the question?

Comment: @TheLizzard it does print True.

Comment: @BryanOakley I'm not sure if matplotlib uses theming, initial googling hasn't turned up anything super obvious. And yes, to be clear, when I execute the first block of code, I get the exact output in the second block of code.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Tk.update()` after creating the window prevents this error from being shown:

```py
import tkinter as tk
Tk = tk.Tk()
Tk.update() ### WE CALL TK.UPDATE()
Tk.destroy()

window1 = tk.Tk()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

f1,ax1 = plt.subplots()

frame1 = tk.Frame(window1,width=300,height=300,bg='blue')
frame1.place(x=0,y=0)

canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f1,frame1)

canvas1.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0,column=0)

canvas1.draw()
```

I'm assuming that the error results from the fact that you're trying to close the window before it actually exists onscreen.